# MySQL combining two queries into single query

Tags: mysql, sql, join, union

My first query looks as below

```
SELECT a.name, b.desc, T3.desc1 as Output
FROM table1 a INNER JOIN
     table2 b
     ON a.id = b.id
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT b2.id, b2.status,  MAX(b2.created_time) as max_time
  FROM q_scan b2
  GROUP BY b2.id  ,  b2.qualys_type
  ) t on t.id = a.id
      AND  t.status=b.status
      AND t.max_time = b.created_time
INNER JOIN table3 T3 on b.tid = T3.tid
WHERE b.status = 'FAIL'
```

My second query looks as below

```
SELECT a.name, b.desc, T4.desc2 as Output
FROM table1 a INNER JOIN
     table2 b
     ON a.id = b.id
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT b2.id, b2.status,  MAX(b2.created_time) as max_time
  FROM q_scan b2
  GROUP BY b2.id  ,  b2.qualys_type
  ) t on t.id = a.id
      AND  t.status=b.status
      AND t.max_time = b.created_time
INNER JOIN table4 T4 on b.tid = T4.tid
WHERE b.status = 'FAIL'
```

In my final result I want `Output column` which will have values either from `T3.desc1` or `T4.desc2`
How can I combine both queries into a single query?

Comment: select ... t1 ... t2 ... (t3 union all t4) ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `table2.id` exists in one of the tables - `table3` or `table4`, a `LEFT JOIN` will simplify the query with the help of `IFNULL()`.

```
SELECT  a.name, 
        b.desc, 
        IFNULL(T3.desc1, T4.desc2) as Output
FROM    table1 a 
        INNER JOIN table2 b ON a.id = b.id
        INNER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT b2.id, b2.status,  MAX(b2.created_time) as max_time
            FROM oac.qualys_scan b2
            GROUP BY b2.id  ,  b2.qualys_type
        ) t on t.id = a.id
              AND  t.status=b.status
              AND t.max_time = b.created_time
        LEFT JOIN table3 T3 on b.tid = T3.tid
        LEFT JOIN table4 T4 on b.tid = T4.tid
WHERE   b.status = 'FAIL'
```