# MYSQL Using Union to combine two queries

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join, union

My first query looks as below

```
SELECT a.name, b.desc, T3.desc1 as Output
FROM table1 a INNER JOIN
     table2 b
     ON a.id = b.id
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT b2.id, b2.status,  MAX(b2.created_time) as max_time
  FROM oac.qualys_scan b2
  GROUP BY b2.id  ,  b2.qualys_type
  ) t on t.id = a.id
      AND  t.status=b.status
      AND t.max_time = b.created_time
INNER JOIN table3 T3 on b.tid = T3.tid
WHERE b.status = 'FAIL'
AND b.type = 'Type1'
```

My second query looks as below

```
SELECT a.name, b.desc, T4.desc2 as Output
FROM table1 a INNER JOIN
     table2 b
     ON a.id = b.id
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT b2.id, b2.status,  MAX(b2.created_time) as max_time
  FROM oac.qualys_scan b2
  GROUP BY b2.id  ,  b2.qualys_type
  ) t on t.id = a.id
      AND  t.status=b.status
      AND t.max_time = b.created_time
INNER JOIN table4 T4 on b.tid = T4.tid
WHERE b.status = 'FAIL'
AND b.type = 'Type2'
```

In my final result I want `Output column` which will have values either from `T3.desc1` or `T4.desc2`
How can I use `UNION` to combine both queries into a single query?

Comment: Very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49023543/mysql-combining-two-queries-into-single-query

Answer (score 0):

just put UNION ALL between the queries. Youll have to alias the columns

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
Query1 UNION Query2; -- for union without duplicates (the set union as in maths)
```

OR

```
Query1 UNION ALL Query2; -- for union with duplicates
```

So it should be:

```
SELECT a.name, b.desc, T3.desc1 as Output
FROM table1 a INNER JOIN
     table2 b
     ON a.id = b.id
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT b2.id, b2.status,  MAX(b2.created_time) as max_time
  FROM oac.qualys_scan b2
  GROUP BY b2.id  ,  b2.qualys_type
  ) t on t.id = a.id
      AND  t.status=b.status
      AND t.max_time = b.created_time
INNER JOIN table3 T3 on b.tid = T3.tid
WHERE b.status = 'FAIL'
AND b.type = 'Type1'

UNION

SELECT a.name, b.desc, T4.desc2 as Output
FROM table1 a INNER JOIN
     table2 b
     ON a.id = b.id
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT b2.id, b2.status,  MAX(b2.created_time) as max_time
  FROM oac.qualys_scan b2
  GROUP BY b2.id  ,  b2.qualys_type
  ) t on t.id = a.id
      AND  t.status=b.status
      AND t.max_time = b.created_time
INNER JOIN table4 T4 on b.tid = T4.tid
WHERE b.status = 'FAIL'
AND b.type = 'Type2';
```